# Check package version meets or exceeds a certain point

Tags: r, package

I am writing a blog post and want to make sure the user has a certain version of a package.  How can I do that in R to give a logical response?  It seems it's possible since we can set minimal version in a package's `Description` file so I'm guessing there's a function in the `tools` package but a search with Google did not reveal it to me.

I can get the version as follows:

```
packageDescription("dplyr")[["Version"]]
```

Ideally I'd want to do:

```
packageDescription("dplyr")[["Version"]]  >= 0.2.0
```

Comment: Study `?packageDescription`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this works:

```
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘0.3.0.2’
> packageVersion("dplyr") >= "0.3.0.2"
[1] TRUE
> packageVersion("dplyr") >= "0.3.0"
[1] TRUE
> packageVersion("dplyr") >= "0.3.0.3"
[1] FALSE
> packageVersion("dplyr") >= "0.3.1.3"
[1] FALSE
> packageVersion("dplyr") >= "0.3.10"
[1] FALSE
> packageVersion("dplyr") >= "0.3.0.10"
[1] FALSE
> packageVersion("dplyr") >= "0.a.0"
Error: invalid version specification ‘0.a.0’
```

Comment: Also `class(packageVersion("dplyr"))` and then `methods(class="numeric_version")` shows that R has a reasonably well-developed set of tools for handling version objects.

Comment: v. 3.01 is minor version 01 == 1, not minor version .01, so 0.3.0000001 is a long-handed way of writing 0.3.1, which is not <= 0.3.0.2